# Adding user control

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I was searching trick to add user control to `datagridview` cell and found the below code. I just copy paste the code but when I try to add the `CustomColumn` then I got error.

This way I try to add `CustomColumn` column to grid.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomColumn cc=new CustomColumn();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cc);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("");
}

public class CustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn {
    public CustomColumn() : base(new CustomeCell()) { }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("It should be a custom Cell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }        
}
public class CustomeCell : DataGridViewCell
{
    public CustomeCell() : base() { }
    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomUserControl);
        }
    }
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        CustomUserControl ctrl = (CustomUserControl)value;
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height);
        ctrl.DrawToBitmap(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height));
        graphics.DrawImage(img, cellBounds.Location);
    }
    protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        List<InfoObject> objs = this.DataGridView.DataSource as List<InfoObject>;
        if (objs != null) 
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < objs.Count) {
                CustomUserControl ctrl = objs[e.RowIndex].Ctrl;
                // Take any action - I will just change the color for now.
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                ctrl.Refresh();
                this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Please show me how to use the above code for adding custom column. I created a user control and name was `CustomUserControl` but no luck. thanks

Comment: What you got error?? can you  past your  error ??

Comment: Please see this good sample :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/ee8eec0b-2b1a-46d2-9d2e-b81828235528/

Comment: i just create a user control and name was CustomUserControl. the user control has one textbox and one button. i just try to simply bind that Custom Column and got error. error was related with casting. may i wrongly used the code to add Custom Column. if any one try the code then see the error. if ossible guide me what to do. thanks

Answer (score -1):

The release of a new plug-in for DataTables called ColVis. ColVis will set a button next to the table, which when activated will show a list of the columns in the table, and the end-user with the option for showing, or hiding the columns.

Try
datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/

Download (place the extracted folder into the "extras" folder in the DataTables distribution):
 datatables.net/releases/ColVis-1.0.1.zip

http://yellowpages.sulekha.com

Comment: i just do not understand what r u trying to say. here i paste my code and try to find out what is the bug but here u talk about another product.

Comment: here i talk about windows not web apps.